# getting old data with AWS elasticsearch -

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, ehcache

I have an object in java which I modified and on local environment I am getting the new data however on AWS elasticsearch, I am still getting the old data.

Is this relate to caching ?

How to proceed on AWS so I can get the new data ?

KR,

Answer (score 0):

You might need to refresh your indices to make updated data available.

You can read following reads and check if that works out or not -

[Elasticsearch Refresh Indices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html)

[Update Indices Settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html)

Comment: @akaliza , did that help you in solving your problem ?